# Keep factoring and concatenating to get a prime?

Tags: factoring

Keep factoring and concatenating,starting from $2$ until we get a prime.

$$2=2$$ $$22=2*11$$$$22211=7*19*167$$ $$22211719167=?$$ ...and so on (the prime factors are arranged from smaller to larger and their multiplicities are also written).

How far we can go with these? (because factorization is very hard)

Comment: how do the exponents work, should we write the prime factors in order of the size of the prime?

Comment: yes multiplication is also written the way they are. i.e. 48=2*2*2*2*3 and then 4822223

Comment: You get a prime in the very first step. 2 is prime.

Comment: @RogerBurt I believe Nana is referring to a prime other than the initial seed.  This looks like a job for a computer program brute force approach.  It will be very difficult to guess as to what prime factors will be on paper, but it is clear that from the second step and beyond, it will never be an even number.

Comment: @RogerBurt yes but here 2 is a starting point

Comment: This is one of those very, very hard problems because the decimal representation of the next number in a certain sense doesn't have much to do with the decimal representations of the previous number and its prime factors. Because increasingly large primes become increasingly rare ("sparse" among the neighboring numbers, on average), probably you will find that in order to answer this question you will have to test incredibly large numbers for primality, which may not be feasible unless you get lucky and the numbers have small prime factors until you reach a prime.

Comment: Yes I meant how far we can go..

Comment: @NanaJ Even that question, it all depends on how small the prime factors are for a given number in your sequence. Is there any easy way to predict when you will finally get a number that has such a large minimum prime factor that you can't compute anymore? I don't think current mathematics can handle this problem, i.e. determine when the smallest prime factor will be $ > N$ for some given $N$ (which I think is the crux of your question).

Comment: @NanaJ "how far do you need to go until a prime is found through this process?"  Unknown at the moment, you will need to program a Matlab code or computer to attempt, and it may take several days or more for the computer to run the code.  I would guess that the smallest prime in the sequence would be millions of digits long.  "How far can we go with this process without worrying about stopping once a prime is found" Indefinitely.  We can go on for as long as we wish and our computers are capable of factoring.

Comment: @JMoravitz maybe we can go to 1200 digits?

Comment: @NanaJ You can make it to just over 100 digits using wolframalpha.  Probably with mathematica or other heavier duty software you can get further, but of course, if you want to keep going and the current software is incapable of handling the request, you are more than welcome to program a prime searching algorithm that can handle **big** numbers and become famous.  I made it to 222117191673111131319549333123883568997108723797801909138725589671825928623195474482364099822833797133 before it stopped factoring for me.

Comment: @JMoravitz okay thanks for your efforts! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [Sage](http://sagemath.org/) available somewhere, you can run this simple code (`n` is the initial value, `b` is the base):

```
n = 2
b = 10
while True :
    s = n.str(b)
    print n.is_prime(), s
    for p,k in factor(n) :
        s += (p.str(b))*k
    n = Integer(s,b)
```

The results I managed to get:

```
True 2
False 22
False 22211
False 22211719167
False 2221171916731111313195493
False 222117191673111131319549333123883568997108723797801
False 222117191673111131319549333123883568997108723797801909138725589671825928623195474482364099822833797133
```

Needed to say, the sequence either gets constant when you hit a prime, or grows so fast that the probability that there is a prime in $\geq k$th step is moreorless equal to the probability that the $a_k$ is a prime, which is $\frac{\ln a_k}{a_k}$. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Using base $8$ arithmetic, it takes two steps:

> $2 = 2$
>
> $22 = 2\cdot2\cdot3\quad$ (In base $10$, this is: $\,\,18= 2\cdot2\cdot3$)
>
> $22223\,\,$ is prime. (In base $10$: $\,\,9371$)

On the other hand, as @JMoravitz pointed out, in base $10$ the number gets big. I tried a [different site](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) and it too got stuck at $2221171916\ldots133$. It's hard to factor numbers with $104$ digits, but the primality test on the site I used indicates that this number is composite; good luck factoring the next one!

It's hard to answer questions like this because the answer depends very much on the way you choose to represent the numbers (e.g., base $10$) as opposed to any relationship from one number to the next.

Comment: thanks,but doing factorization in other base is not too interesting for me

Comment: @NanaJ What makes it interesting in base 10?

Comment: because base 10 is the 'MAN'

Comment: "The 'MAN'" is trying to keep you down.

Comment: nice...............+1

Answer (score 0):

If the initial seeds are 3,5,or 7 instead of 2,then we get a prime very quickly,i.e.33311,55511,and 77711 are all primes!. If 2 is the initial seed then that last number 22211719167.....797133 is divisible by 3 eight times(!)and it not divisible by any other primes less than 10^5